# Loading a backbone.js subview from within the parent view using requireJS

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, synchronous

I am loading a requireJS module that contains a backbone view.  Inside that view, during the "initialization" a subView, which is contained in a separate module, is loaded as well.  After this is complete, I'd like to add a listener to the newly loaded subview.  However, this operation fails because the child module, which was supposed to be loaded, is not yet registered for whatever reason.  In the code below, when I log "that.childModule," it returns an undefined value, which should not be the case if the module was loading correctly.  What could be the problem

```
//Sample of a requireJS module that contains a backbone view, which in turn loads other subviews

define(function (require) {
    //Narrate dependencies
    'use strict';
    var $ = require('jquery');
    var _ = require('underscore');
    var Backbone = require('backbone');

    //Create the parentView
    var ParentView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function() {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render');
            this.render();

        //Make the subViews
            var that = this;
        require([
                'models/common/childModel',
                'views/common/childView'
            ], function(ChildModel, ChildView){
                that.ChildModule = new ChildView({
                    el: $(".theDiv", that.el), 
                    model: new ChildModel()
                });
            });
            console.log(that.ChildModule)
            this.listenTo(this.ChildModule.model, 'change:focus', this.blur);
        },
        render: function() {
            $(this.el).addClass('something');
            $(this.el).append('<div class="theDiv"></div>');;
            return this;
        },
    });

    return ParentView;
});
```

Comment: Can you post a JSFiddle including the childModel and childView modules?

Comment: why not require your childModel and childView where you require Backbone, jQuery and Underscore?

Comment: @JanSommer, that is what I ended up doing.  However, I'm curious as to why the above method won't work?

Comment: Your childModel is loaded asynchronously but your code assumes it's loaded synchronously. By putting your require statement at the top of your function, RequireJS sees this and loads your childModel behind the scenes BEFORE executing your function. This makes it look like you're coding in a synchronous fashion, but in reality this is not the case.

Comment: I assumed it had something to do with synchronicity.  Just out of curiosity, what is the "cut-off" for a file being loaded synchronously?  If I put it at the top, its synchronous, but if its farther down, its asynchronous?  Or is it that once I start using non-"requireJS" code, it loads all future module calls asynchronously?